# Program is giving me a "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

This is the code I am using for my program

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This program will read the information from the 
 * txt file and will organize and output the information
 * in a clean and understandable manner 
 */
public class Project3_S_B {// Open class container
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { // Open main method
        
        File file = new File("M:\\Rooms2.txt"); //This gets the txt file from my computers file explorer

        Scanner txtFile = new Scanner(file); //This scans the txt file that was pulled from my computer

        String roomName =""; //variable that will hold the value for the name of each room
        String roomShade = ""; //variable that will hold the value for the shade choice chosen
        String acType = ""; //variable that will hold the value for Air Conditioner type
        String acManufacturer = ""; //variable that will hold the value for the Air Conditioner manufacturer
        double roomLength = 0.0; //variable that will hold the value for the rooms length 
        double roomCoolingCapacity = 0.0; //variable that will hold the value for the rooms cooling capacity
        Double acCoolingCapacity = 0.0;
        double roomWidth = 0.0; //variable that will hold the value for the rooms width 

        ArrayList<Room> room = new ArrayList<Room>(); //This is the array list for the room name and its information

        ArrayList<AirConditioner> airconditioner = new ArrayList<AirConditioner>(); //This is the array list for the Air Conditioner and its information

    while(txtFile.hasNext()){ //This while loop will organize the information from the txt file into its categories

        txtFile.next();

        roomName = txtFile.next();

        roomLength = txtFile.nextDouble();

        roomWidth = txtFile.nextDouble();

        roomShade = txtFile.next();

        acManufacturer = txtFile.next();

        acType = txtFile.next();

        acCoolingCapacity = txtFile.nextDouble();

        txtFile.nextLine();


        if(txtFile.hasNext()){ //This will repeat the while loop if there arew more lines than the while loop accounts for
        
            txtFile.nextLine();

            txtFile.nextLine();

        }

        Room r = new Room(roomName, roomLength, roomWidth, roomShade);

        room.add(r);

        AirConditioner a = new AirConditioner(acManufacturer, acType, roomCoolingCapacity);

        airconditioner.add(a);

    }

    for(int i =0; i < room.size(); i++){ //This for loop will output the information from the txt file
        System.out.println("Room Name: " +room.get(i) .getroomName());
        
        System.out.println("Room Area(in square feet): " +room.get(i) .getroomArea());

        System.out.println("Amount of Shade: " +room.get(i) .getroomShade());

        System.out.printf("BTU Per hour needed: %,.0f", room.get(i) .calroomCoolingCapacity());

        System.out.println("Air Conditioner Manufacturer: " +airconditioner.get(i) .getacManufacturer());

        System.out.println("Air Conditioner Type: " +airconditioner.get(i) .getacType());

        System.out.printf("Air Conditioner Cooling Capacity (BTUs Per Hour): %,.0f" +airconditioner.get(i) .getacCoolingCapacity());
    
        System.out.println("" +room.get(i) .hasAdequateCooling());
    
    }
    
    } //Close main method
} //Close class container
```

And this is the error that it is giving me when I try to run it

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)       
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)    
        at Project3_S_B.main(Project3_S_B.java:38)
```

I looked at all the issues it could have been and all of my data types match up with the ones on the txt file. A friend recommended I try exception handling, but I don't see how I could incorporate that into my code and even if I could, I was instructed not to use it in my code.

```
Master Bathroom
10
15.5
Abundant
GE
Portable
8000

Master Bedroom
16
16.25
Moderate
Frigidaire
Portable
8000

Living Room
30
25
Little
Whirlpool
Window Mounted
18000

Kitchen
20
12
Moderate
GE
Window Mounted
6000
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Scanner uses your machine's default Locale.
If you change it, it works:

> txtFile.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

It says the exception occurs in line 38:

> roomName = txtFile.next();

Can you show your txt file? I never user Scanner(), so I'd like to test your code.

Comment: @Spectric tell that to Stackoverflow. I can't comment.

Comment: @Asdra My bad :P